# Custom Class in Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Within my Controller I have a class called "ObjectData" that contains an ID and a string:

```
public class ObjectData
{
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a List of these to the view via ViewBag, but I don't know how to loop through the items in the array since the classtype isn't normal.  I'm doing it this way because I don't want to pass a bunch of Objects and their data to the view, when I only need the ID and Name (is this a valid concern?).

I'm thinking of looping through like this:

```
foreach (ObjectData i in ViewBag.ParentSetIds)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(i.Name, "Detail", new { objectId = i.ObjectId }, null)
}
```

But Razor doesn't recognize that class type.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: can you rename this question? It's not indicative of your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You must fully qualify your typename on the line:

```
foreach (Put.Your.Namespaces.Here.ObjectData i in ViewBag.ParentSetIds)
```

Razor do not use the same `using` declaration as your controllers. You may use `web.config` in the View directory to add such namespaces not to fully qualify it everytime.

Regarding the question if you should be concerned about passing such objects to view. No, there is no need to worry about it. I suggest to move the object `ObjectData` from controller to the folder next to the controllers folder named `ModelView` or `ViewModel` and create the class here. This is something like publicly accepted "hack" to have models which represents just another view on some "real" model. It is same like when you generate MVC3 project it creates for you file `AccountModels.cs` which contains exactly the same kind of models. But you find it in `Model` folder, while it may be discussed if it should be rather in `ViewModel` folder. Also, pass this data as Model not as the part ViewBag if it is not really just helping data.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with two things here. Firstly, "Razor do not use the same using declaration" is incorrect. There is an `@using` directive available in your Razor views. Also, ViewModels aren't a "publicly accepted hack".. I would say they are a "universally accepted design decision".

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
foreach (var i in ViewBag.ParentSetIds)
```

And let the compiler determine the namespace based on the ViewBag.ParentSetIds

Answer (score 0):

> Within my **Controller** I have a **class** called "ObjectData" that contains
>   an ID and a string:

Wait, what? Why do you have a class in your controller?

> I'm trying to pass a List of these to the view via ViewBag,

Just use a view model. If you are, you can make `List<ObjectData>` part of it. In your controller, you load up that list (lets call it `ObjectDataList`), and send it to your view.

In the view (razor), you'd have something like:

```
@model MyProject.MyModel

@foreach(var i in Model.ObjectDataList)
{
   @Html.ActionLink(i.Name, "Detail", new { objectId = i.ObjectId }, null)
}
```

Edit:

For clarification, your view model could be:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public string Title {get;set;}
     public List<ObjectData> ObjectDataList {get;set;}

}
```